# Программирование через интерфейсы

Tags: java

Всем добрый день ! Я только начал изучать Java. Подскажите как правильно программировать через интерфейсы . Много о них слышал но не видел практического применения.  А хочется разобраться получше.

Comment: А чем Вас не устроила глава о интерфейсах в книге, по которой Вы изучаете Java?

Comment: "Программировать через графический интерфейс?" Почитайте это, возможно это поможет: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality_ru.html
http://eax.me/java-swing/

Comment: Интерфейс - это как абстрактный класс, ток немного другой. Используется для "множественного наследования" например и в особых случаях